# How to load data from Firestore using keys

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, shopping-cart

I'm trying to build an e-commerce app using Flutter and Firestore, I'm having a challenge in building the cart. using the codes below, I have been able to get the products a user wishes to add to the cart using the product id. My challenge is how to use the id or the keys to fetch the details of the products from Firestore and store the cart products either in Firestore or SQLite so that I can query from there and display them on the cart page.

appstate.dart

```
class AppStateModel extends Model {

  final Map<int, int> _productsInCart = <int, int>{};

  Map<int, int> get productsInCart => Map<int, int>.from(_productsInCart);



  void addProductToCart(int productId) {
    if (!_productsInCart.containsKey(productId)) {
      _productsInCart[productId] = 1;
    } else {
      _productsInCart[productId]++;
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }


  void removeItemFromCart(int productId) {
    if (_productsInCart.containsKey(productId)) {
      if (_productsInCart[productId] == 1) {
        _productsInCart.remove(productId);
      } else {
        _productsInCart[productId]--;
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearCart() {
    _productsInCart.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

product_display.dart
page with onPressed function to get the id of the item clicked to add to cart

```
  CupertinoActionSheetAction(
    child: const Text('Add To Cart'),
      onPressed: () {
   model.addProductToCart(products[index].id);
  },
)
```

product.dart

```
class Products{
 final  String category;
 final  String description;
 final  int id;
 final int  price;
 final  String title;
 final  String url;


 const Products( {this.category,this.description,this.id, this.price, this.title, this.url,
 });


}
```

CartProduct.dart

```
class CartProducts{
 final  String category;
 final  String description;
 final  int id;
 final int  price;
 final  String title;
 final  String url;


 const CartProducts( {this.category,this.description,this.id, this.price, this.title, this.url,
 });


}
```

Now let say I have products with ids 1, 4, 6, 9, 11 in product cart, when I print in the console using print(model.productsInCart.keys), this was the output (1, 4, 6, 9, 11), now my challenge is how to use these ids to query the products with ids 1,4,6,9,11 from Firestore collection products and store them either in Firebase or SQLite so that I can display them in the cart page for a user to view his/her items in cart.

[image: firestore database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do is

```
Firestore.instance.collection("collection").document("id").get().then((querySnapshot){
    print(querySnapshot.data);
  });
```

Obviously replace collection with your collection name and id with the id you are trying to fetch. Here I am using `.then` syntax, but you can pass everything before `.then` to the `FutureBuilder` as usual.

**Edit:**
You'll need to add a helper method for fetching all the data from the firestore.

```
Future<List<Products>> getCollection() async {
  List<int> idList = [];
  // productsInCart[key] = value; where key is id and value is amount in cart
  productsInCart.forEach((key, value) {
    idList.add(key);
  });
  List<Products> productList = [];
  for (var id in idList) {
    var documents = (await Firestore.instance
            .collection('products')
            .where('id', isEqualTo: id)
            .getDocuments())
        .documents;
    if (documents.length > 0) {
      var doc = documents[0]
          .data; // if there are multiple documents with given id get first document
      var prod = Products(
          id: doc['id'],
          title: doc['title'],
          price: doc['price'],
          category: doc['category'],
          description: doc['description']);
      productList.add(prod);
    }
  }
  return productList;
}
```

then use FutureBuilder to build the list

```
FutureBuilder<List<Products>>(
  future: getCollection(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var list = snapshot.data;
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("${list[index].title}"),
                subtitle: Text(
                    "Amount in cart : ${productsInCart[list[index].id]}"),
              ));
    } else {
      return Text("");
    }
  },
);
```

I am using `Future` and `FutureBuilder` instead of `Stream` and `StreamBuilder`, because having to query using multiple ids is a tedious task in cloud firestore, since firestore doesn't have official support for **Logical OR**. So having to gather data from multiple stream sources is difficult. Using FutureBuilder has the same output as using StreamBuilder as long as product detail is not being changed while app is being used.

**Edit 2:**
To use multiple stream sources use StreamGroup from [async](https://pub.dev/packages/async) package. Here is what final code looks like

```
Stream<List<Products>> _getCollection() async* {
  List<int> idList = [];
  // productsInCart[key] = value; where key is id and value is amount in cart
  productsInCart.forEach((key, value) {
    idList.add(key);
  });
  StreamGroup<QuerySnapshot> streamGroup = StreamGroup();
  for (var id in idList) {
    var stream = Firestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: id)
        .snapshots();
    streamGroup.add(stream);
  }
  //using map to store productDetails so that same products from multiple stream events don't get added multiple times.
  Map<int, Products> productMap = {};
  await for (var val in streamGroup.stream) {
    var documents = val.documents;
    var doc = documents[0].data;
    var product = Products.fromMap(doc);
    productMap[product.id] = product;
    yield productMap.values.toList();
  }
}
```

```
StreamBuilder<List<Products>>(
  stream: _getCollection(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var values = snapshot.data;
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: values.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(values[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(
                    "Amount in cart : ${productsInCart[values[index].id]}"),
              ));
    } else {
      print("There is no data");
      return Text("");
    }
  },
),
```

I've added named constructor for convenience

```
Products.fromMap(Map map) {
  this.id = map['id'];
  this.title = map['title'];
  this.description = map['description'];
  this.price = map['price'];
  this.category = map['category'];
}
```

Comment: @tomgates I've edited my answer. Please check if it answered your question.

Comment: @tomgates I'm having hard time understanding what is your problem. I've made second edit. See if this solves your issue?? If not please provide proper description of what you are trying to do, and where you are stuck or having problems.

Comment: @ Kshitij Dhakal, I think I had the whole idea wrong, I have edited my question, please.

Comment: @ Kshitij Dhakal, The first solution worked though, but the problem again is whenever the state of the app changes like stopped or restarted, the products in the cart are lost since they are not being stored anywhere.What I want to achieve now is after successfully querying the related ids from Firestore, now save them in SQLite or a Firestore collection called let say productsInCart and query from there and display them in the cart page instead so that even when the app is stopped or restarted, an authenticated user can see what is already added to cart that has not been checked out yet.

Comment: Hey @tomgates I'd be happy to help you, but your last request is out of the scope of this question. There isn't enough information for me to know how are you adding product in the cart (since this is where most would use db to create cart). So please either issue new question or we can continue in the chat where you can give more information. PS. Please don't extend your question beyond it's intended purpose in future.

Comment: @ Kshitij Dhakal, Asking a new question with what I have achieved now.Thanks